# modify local variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

the descriptionPercentagesStr variable is not modified in the success queryExt.first.

I think it is a syntax error but can not find.

```
   var ProductExtendidoClass = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
    var productExtObj = new ProductExtendidoClass();
    var idProduct =this.model.attributes.id;
    var queryExt = new Parse.Query(ProductExtendidoClass);

    descriptionPercentagesStr="inicial";


    queryExt.equalTo("idProduct", idProduct);

    queryExt.first({
      success: function(productExtObj) {

        if (productExtObj!=null)// se tiene el producto
        {
        );
           $("input[name=description_percentages]").val(productExtObj.get("descriptionPercentages"));
           descriptionPercentagesStr=productExtObj.get("descriptionPercentages");

        }
        else
        {
          //alert("lengt es menor o igual a 0");

        }
        // Successfully retrieved the object.
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  alert(descriptionPercentagesStr);
```

Comment: $("input[name=description_percentages]").val(productExtObj.get("descriptionPercentages"));
           descriptionPercentagesStr=productExtObj.get("descriptionPercentages"); what is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `first` query function is asynchronous.  The `success` and `failure` functions are its callbacks and are called at a later arbitrary time when the query completes.  They are not called sequentially as with the rest of your code.  So the order of operations in your code is as follows:

1. Set `descriptionPercentagesStr` to "inicial"
2. Query the `ProductExtendidoClass` for the matching `idProduct` (results not received yet)
3. Alert `descriptionPercentagesStr` (returns "inicial")
4. Query completes at some later time and `descriptionPercentagesStr` is set to the result

You can verify this behavior by adding `alert(descriptionPercentagesStr);` into the `success` callback function.  It should output the result from Parse.